# The provided Google API key is invalid due to Error Code: InvalidKeyOrUnauthorizedURLMapError

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, maps

I followed the Google tutorial on how to generate an API key for browser however I am unable to load the map due to error with invalid key.

None of the solutions posted to related issue worked in my case.

This is my code:

```
    <head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>myTitle</title> 

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY"
  type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
```

Web console log:

```
    "ApiNotActivatedMapError: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key" main.js line 61 > eval:50:381
Nr/this.j</<() main.js line 61 > eval:50
as</<() main.js line 61 > eval:54
Ar/d() main.js line 61 > eval:43
<anonymous> AuthenticationService.Authenticate:1
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using some libraries like place library or geocode?

Remove API Key and try.

If use then try this -:

```
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

If not use then try this -:

```
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```